# Autofocus on textbox on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a UI. In my HTML, I have a paragraph element with some text. When the user clicks on the paragraph, the `<p>` element turns into a text area with the same text displayed (for editing purposes). However, in order to start typing in the textarea, the user must click again in order to display the cursor. How would I set this up so that the cursor displays instantly on click and the user is able to begin typing after one click (and not two)?

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: did you consider using [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.focus()` on the element within your click event.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Autofocus method. It'll help you.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a `textarea` and give it the focus, use Mooseman answers. However, there's an even simpler way of handling this, with something less "bulky" than a `textarea`. With the `contentEditable`  property, almost any HTML element can be edited.

Example :

```
<p contentEditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</p>
```

By clicking on the element, an outline will appear and you will be able to change the text. When the element lose focus, the outline automatically disappears.

You can use Javascript/JQuery to do anything you like, or to add the property dynamically to the elements (ex: when the user double-clicks on it, or something like that).

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable).

**Note** I'm aware that this isn't really the point of your question, but this will help you achieve a very similar result easily, so I thought it was worth mentionning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**contentEditable**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) property with JavaScript to handle this, here's a DEMO of what you want to achieve:

```js
var parag = document.getElementById("paragraph");
parag.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.contentEditable = "true";
});
parag.addEventListener("change", function() {
  this.contentEditable = "false";
});
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</p>
```

- Use `onclick` event to set `contentEditable = "true"` in the `<p>`
  element.
- And `onchange` event to set `contentEditable = "false"` back.